# IE6 rendering bug. Some parsed <li> elements are losing their closing tags

Tags: html, internet-explorer-6

I have been working with IE6 for many years [sob], but have never seen this particular bug before, and I can't seem to find a reference to it on the Web. The problem appears to be with how IE6 is parsing the HTML of a nested list. Even though the markup is correct, IE6 somehow munges the code when it is parsed, and drops the closing tags of some of the `<li>` elements.

For example, take the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href=''>Child A</a>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href=''>Grandchild A</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
       </li>
       <li><a href=''>The Child B Which Is Not A</a>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href=''>Grandchild B</a></li>
                    <li><a href=''>Grandchild C</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href=''>Deep Purple</a></li>
      <li><a href=''>Led Zeppelin</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now take a look at how IE6 renders this code, after it has run it through the IE6 rendering engine:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>My Page</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
    <DIV>
        <UL>
            <LI><A href="">Child A</A> 
                <DIV>
                    <UL>
                        <LI><A href="">Grandchild A</A> </LI>
                    </UL>
                </DIV>
            <LI><A href="">The Child B Which Is Not A</A> 
                <DIV>
                    <UL>
                        <LI><A href="">Grandchild B</A> 
                        <LI><A href="">Grandchild C</A> </LI>
                    </UL>
                </DIV>
            <LI><A href="">Deep Purple</A> 
            <LI><A href="">Led Zeppelin</A> </LI>
        </UL>
    </DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Note how on some of the `<li>` elements there are no longer any closing tags, even though it existed in the source HTML.

Does anyone have any idea what could be triggering this bug, and if it is possible to avoid it? It seems to be the source of some visual display problems in IE6.

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you try other DocTypes?

Comment: Please don't care about IE6 if it's not REQUIRED REQUIRED. IE6 must namely die, but that dying process goes to slow.

Comment: What are the visual display problems?

Comment: Yes, the problem persists with at least XHTML 1.0 Transitional. I haven't tested it with other doctypes. I will try some tests with other doctype configurations - that's a good idea, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I know - I wish IE a painful, painful, but quick death. If only it would come to pass. :(

Comment: The visual display problem is that I have a bottom border applied to each `<li>` element. When I mouse over an element that has a nested `<div>` the bottom border disappears. A strange bug that I have never seen before.

Comment: @ntownsend - I tried this with no doctype declaration (aka Quirks Mode), and got the same result. I think this is just a bug, and that is the beginning and the end of it.

Comment: @Jeff Fohl - How are you applying the bottom border? Do you have mouseover handlers on any of the elements in the list? Is it possible to see all of the actual code involved?

Comment: Yes, there are mouseovers and some complex JS and CSS on the actual site. In order to simplify things, and not present a huge bunch of code for people to sift through, I was trying to isolate this particular problem of not closing the <li> elements, because that looked very peculiar, and I thought that might be the source of the problem.

Comment: @Jeff Fohl - I don't think it has anything to do with it. This is most likely a result of the JS, CSS and mouseover functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `</li>` is not required in pure HTML (non-XHTML) mode. The same applies to `</p>` and a few more closing tags. The IE6 engine might have "optimized" them away somehow.

Here's an extract from the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2) about the `<li>` element:

> ```
> <!ELEMENT LI - O (%flow;)*             -- list item -->
> <!ATTLIST LI
>   %attrs;                              -- %coreattrs, %i18n, %events --
>   >
> ```
>
> Start tag: **required**, End tag: **optional**

Note the last line.

The visual display problems you're talking about are more often related to [hasLayout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) [bugs](http://haslayout.net/css/).

Comment: Is it just not required to display properly, or will leaving off the closing tags of `<li>` and `<p>` actually validate?

Comment: It's valid HTML, so yes, it will validate. Also see [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html).

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that IE6 is eliminating SOME of the `</li>` tags, not all of them. If it was eliminating all of them, this might not be a problem. Even though the doctype I included above is HTML5, in our production environment we are using XHTML, so I need to close the elements. I have tried every hasLayout trick in the book (position:relative, zoom:1, height:1%, etc) to no avail.

Comment: It may be worth the effort to ask a direct question about the particular problem. This rendering behaviour is imo not related.

Comment: Thanks BalusC. I guess this is as close to answer as there is. But, I think the actual answer to the question, "Why is this happening?" is, "Because it is a bug in IE6." Big surprise!